# Displaying Json Data into UITableView in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have data from the server in a format as:

```
{"articles":
[{"articleId":"1",
"articleName":"<\/head> Some text<\/body><\/html>"},
{"articleId":"2","articleName":"<\/head>Some Text Again<\/body<\/html>"}
```

I have no idea how to display that it in a UITableView.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, It depends on your requirement of how you want to display this ind=formation into your UITableViewCell.

1. First store your response in an array of dictionary which will then be act as the datasource for your UITableView.
2. You can append the recieved response array into this local data structure.

Rest, It'll be my pleasure to provide next steps if you require.

P.S.: I suggest you to make the context of this question more clear.